# How can I use the sum of squares formula to create blocks of a certain dimension?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

The previous expression was just the sum of consecutive squares so $1^2+2^2+...+n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

I know how to derive this formula but can someone please explain the claim that

"This expression says that a box with dimensions $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ should contain six copies of $1^2+2^2+...+n^2$"

For a box that has a 4 x 5 x 9 dimension, $n=4$

So I have to construct a video out of individual $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2$ building units

I have no idea what this means. $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2 = 30$ cubes in total and  4 x 5 x 9 = 180 unit squares.

So am I supposed to build this with $1^2$ unit squares and $2^2 = 4$, 2 x 2 squares and $3^2=9$, 3 x 3 squares and $4^2 = 16$ 4 x 4 squares? and if so how can I organize it so that the box has dimensions 4 x 5 x 9?

I don't know how to organize the blocks and I don't know if my interpretation of the problem is correct?

EDIT: He also says that there should be 6 units? That means only six blocks? How is he getting that?

EDIT: stacking blocks

1B

2B 2B

3B 3B 3B

4B 4B 4B 4B

4B 4B 4B 4B

3B 3B 3B

```
  2B 2B


     1B
```

Then combine so

1B 4B 4B 4B 4B

2B 2B 3B 3B 3B

3B 3B 3B 2B 2B

4B 4B 4B 4B 1B

Comment: It means $6$ of each block type.

Comment: 6 1 x 1, 6 2 x 2, 6 3 x 3 and 6 4 x 4?

Comment: Yes, though it seems difficult enough for me to solve without having the blocks infront of me. Geogebra 3d fails me as well. Do you know any software that can do the trick? I am willing to place the blocks manually, but graphing each block is way too tedious.

Comment: maybe just write out 1B, 2B, 3B, 4B for the blocks representing 1 x1, 2 x 2, etc. and then stack them up? I can show you an example if I'm unclear on what I'm saying.

Comment: I understand, but it is harder to visualize $3d$ blocks that way.

Comment: that's true, I'm sorry I don't know of any way to graph the blocks

Comment: Well, no problem. I will ask around in the chats. Do you have the blocks with you at the moment? If so, keep trying.

Comment: i don't have any blocks at the moment. I ordered some from amazon and it should reach in a few hours but i'm just trying to understand conceptually first. i found this article that helps a lot https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/the-sum-of-consecutive-squares-formula/ but I'm still a little confused

Comment: should I make 6 pyramids with the bottom layer as a 4 x 4 then next as 3 x 3  then 2 x 2  then 1 x 1 and then combine them all to make a 4 x 5 x 9 box?

Comment: just like the person did in the pictures at the bottom of the link i posted?

Comment: Doing that is practically impossible. You will definitely not get a $4*5*9$ cuboid.

Comment: but what about what the person did in the link?

Comment: Unfortunately the link doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88310/discussion-between-mohammad-zuhair-khan-and-user477465).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make 6 pyramid like structures starting with a base of 4 x 4, then on top 3 x 3, then 2 x 2 then 1 x 1. then I can combine them all. I found this from 
https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/the-sum-of-consecutive-squares-formula/

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: every time i do, it says i cannot accept my own answer

Comment: it says i have to wait 2 days lol

Comment: See [Can I answer my own question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center.

Comment: yes but i have to wait 2 days before i can do it lol